# Adjusting the the number of Vertices in a non-manifold edge

Tags: python

I have two separate objects. Object 1 (Grey) has 154 vertices in the Non-Manifold Edge and Object 2 (Orange) has 112. I would ideally like to have an equal number, so when I join these two objects and perform a Bridge Edge Loop, the result will be an even mesh of quads.

Perhaps someone could help with a python script to reduce the 154 to 112?
Merging by distance is not possible, as the edges in both objects are different in length.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it to do it for one model or several times? Because if one time of few, I don't think the operation is worth a script.

Comment: Merging by distance, hitting _M > Merge by Distance_? This merges vertices that are closer to each other than the set distance. It's irrelevant if those edges are different in length - because all vertices within this distance are merged into one.
It won't bridge gaps between edges further away than the vertices defining the edges.
But you can use it to reduce the vertices on the edge which has too many. With that edge selected, choose _Merge by Distance_ and adjust the _Merge Distance_ until it says "Removed 42 vertice(s)". If you don't get that number, try less and merge some manually.

Comment: It is for many different objects lemon, so a script would be required. Merging by Distance seems the way to go Gordon, yet the user would have to do many calculations.